# How to prevent rest-client from opening a http response in split screen in VsCode?

Tags: http, visual-studio-code, rest-client

I'm trying to change the settings of the VSCode extension: `Rest-Client` (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client).
My goal would be to open http responses simply in new tabs instead of splitting the screen.
Current functionality:
[image]

Desired functionality:
[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.